# Flutter stuck at Installing build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk after migrating flutter app to AndroidX

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am using below packages in my project, after running console threw me error saying its incompatible with AndroidX, So i followed the steps given in   https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/androidx-compatibility and said flutter run ...console just stucks

Added in project/app/gradle.build

```
defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.driver_app_flutter"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
```

Added in gradle.properties:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

pubspec.yaml

```
  cloud_firestore: ^0.9.7
  firebase_auth: ^0.8.1+4
  google_sign_in: ^4.0.1+1
```

flutter doctor -v

```
~/flutter_projects/driver_app_flutter$ flutter doctor -v
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, v1.7.8+hotfix.3, on Linux, locale en_IN)
    • Flutter version 1.7.8+hotfix.3 at /data/EMBITEL/emb-rajekri/Downloads/flutter
    • Framework revision b712a172f9 (3 days ago), 2019-07-09 13:14:38 -0700
    • Engine revision 54ad777fd2
    • Dart version 2.4.0


[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /data/EMBITEL/emb-rajekri/Android/Sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.0
    • Java binary at: /opt/android-studio/jre/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1343-b16-5323222)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.4)
    • Android Studio at /opt/android-studio
    • Flutter plugin version 37.0.1
    • Dart plugin version 183.6270
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1343-b16-5323222)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.35.1)
    • VS Code at /usr/share/code
    • Flutter extension version 3.2.0

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • Android SDK built for x86 • emulator-5554 • android-x86 • Android 9 (API 28) (emulator)

• No issues found!
```

Comment: Delete the build folder and try again, it should help.

Comment: @fayeed i tried but it didnt work for me thanks for replying.

Comment: @RajeshPatil Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

This process helped me to solve the issue(Using cmd)-

1.[Connect to the device with ADB](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vr0GLIufzkM&t=187s)

**2.Use "adb uninstall com.example.application.name"**

Answer (score 1):

Run the app by running `flutter run -v` in console.

it prints the reason why it can't launch the app.

Comment: Only rather it should be `flutter run -v`. Thank you, your suggestion prompted an answer. I wonder how important the basic things that are quickly forgotten

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your applicationId inside "android/app/build.gradle", that worked for me..